# Multiple Restangular services with different run time configurations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service, restangular

I'm dealing with an AngularJS (v1.6) + Restangular (v1.6.1) single page application and I'm struggling to get 2 different Restangular services to work as I expect to.

The idea is to retrieve a list of ProductTypes from the back-end and then a list of Products for each type the final user is allowed to interact with;
keep in mind that ProductTypes and Products APIs use different base URLs.

> ***The problem:***
>
> the products element transformers are never called: what am I doing wrong?

I tried the following approach:

```
// index.js file
// here I require everything the web-app needs...
angular.
  module('ProductReader', ['ui.router', 'restangular'])
  .config(ProductTypesConfig)
  .config(Routing)
  .service('ProductsRestangular', ProductsRestangular)
  .constant('PRODUCT_TYPES_CONST', PRODUCT_TYPES_CONST)
  .constant('PRODUCTS_CONST', PRODUCTS_CONST);

// PRODUCT_TYPES_CONST file
PRODUCT_TYPES_CONST = {
  API_URL: 'product_types_api',
  ENDPOINT: 'product_types'
};

module.exports = PRODUCT_TYPES_CONST;

// PRODUCTS_CONST file
PRODUCTS_CONST = {
  API_URL: 'products_api',
  TYPES: {}
    /**
     * here the structure built via the config below should be looking like the following 
     * TYPES: {
        PRODUCT_TYPE_1: {
          ENDPOINT: 'product_type_1'
        },
        PRODUCT_TYPE_2: {
          ENDPOINT: 'product_type_2'
        }
     }
    */
}

module.exports = PRODUCTS_CONST;

// ProductTypesConfig file
/** @ngInject */
function ProductTypesConfig(RestangularProvider, PRODUCT_TYPES_CONST, PRODUCTS_CONST) {
  
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(PRODUCT_TYPES_CONST.API_URL);

  //ProductTypes
  RestangularProvider
    .addElementTransformer(PRODUCT_TYPES_CONST.ENDPOINT, false, function(productType) {

      PRODUCTS_CONST.TYPES[productType.name.toUpperCase()] = {
        ENDPOINT: productType.endpoint
      }

      //Products
      RestangularProvider
        .addElementTransformer(productType.endpoint, false, function(singleProduct) {
          let frontEndSingleProductStuff = {};
          
          // ... here stuff is added to the object above...

          return angular.extend(rw9Item, {
            frontEnd: frontEndSingleProductStuff
          });
          
        });
      
      return productType;
    });
}

module.exports = ProductTypesConfig;

// Products Custom Factory
/** @ngInject */
function ProductsRestangular(Restangular, PRODUCTS_CONST) {

  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl(PRODUCTS_CONST.API_URL);
  });
}

module.exports = ProductsRestangular;

// Routing file
/** @ngInject */
function Routing($stateProvider, PRODUCT_TYPES_CONST) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('landing', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/product-reader',
      resolve: {
        productTypes: function(Restangular, PRODUCT_TYPES_CONST) {
          return Restangular.all(PRODUCT_TYPES_CONST.ENDPOINT).getList();
        },
      }
    })
    .state('product-list', {
      parent: 'landing',
      url: '/list/{:productType}',
      resolve: {
        productLists: function($transition$, ProductsRestangular, PRODUCTS_CONST) {
          return ProductsRestangular.all(PRODUCTS_CONST[$transition$.params().productType].ENDPOINT).getList();
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: so what result do you get when the route gets executed?

Comment: A list of products of course, but since no transformer was actually used in the process every product lacks the `frontEndSingleProductStuff` needed to work properly in the front-end

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You need to fetch all the product types and in scope of every product type you want also to fetch relevant products. and each product type may have own end point to retrieve the product. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @skyboyer here's the workflow just to be clear:

>I have a ProductTypes endpoint to retrieve them

>once I retrieve all the ProductTypes successfully (it's an array fyi) each one of the ProductTypes will expose to me a different endpoint

>for each ProductType I use the aforementioned endpoint to retrieve its list of actual Products of that specific type

Comment: so you are trying to append additional addElementTransformer only when you call for product types. it means that you are trying to configure server after it has been already created. what can you do? you better have 2 different services based on Restangular. For second service(ProductService) you would be able to set up baseUrl dynamically through `withConfig`  and you wouldn't even need addElementTransformer but use `.then` chain instead.

Comment: I already have 2 different configured services, the ProductTypes (used with the first Restangular configuration) and the ProductsRestangular, the point is that even if the elementTransformers are correctly inherited from the former one, they are just not coming into play when the Products are retrieved. Moreover, it's better to use the Restangular hooks to modify the model upon receiving it, instead of using a `.then` approach somewhere else: you are just rewriting something you already have.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple `Restangular` API URL services are configured like this:

```
factory("service1", ["Restangular", function(restangular) {
  return restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {

    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl("http://localhost:8090/apiws");

  });

}]);


factory("service2", ["Restangular", function(restangular) {
  return restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {

    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl("http://localhost:8080/api");
    RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHeaders({
      "Authorization": "Basic 123345667",
    });

  });

}]);
```

For more info see the Official [docs](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#adding-custom-methods-to-collections)

Comment: I set up a Restangular object with a different configuration in my code, but its elementTransformer inherited from the first Restangular object is present but not being called